# Building an image with buildah I'm getting: EMFILE: too many open files

Tags: npm, buildah

When I run `buildah bud`, I'm getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! code EMFILE
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/cd/a5/aca06eccd914d83e3be09412f45e00ceac1150a83df0e32d015284f4c8f6
npm ERR! errno -24
npm ERR! EMFILE: too many open files, open '/root/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/cd/a5/aca06eccd914d83e3be09412f45e00ceac1150a83df0e32d015284f4c8f6'
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be solved with [this method using `--ulimit`](https://github.com/containers/buildah/issues/2230#issuecomment-708620712)

```bash
buildah bud --ulimit nofile=4096:4096
```

### Explaination of `--ulimit nofile=4096:4096`

The option is documented in [`buildah build`](https://github.com/rhatdan/buildah/blob/master/docs/buildah-build.1.md),

> `--ulimit type=soft-limit[:hard-limit]`
>
> Specifies resource limits to apply to processes launched when processing RUN instructions. This option can be specified multiple times. Recognized resource types include:
>
> - "core": maximum core dump size (`ulimit -c`)
> - "cpu": maximum CPU time (`ulimit -t`)
> - "data": maximum size of a process's data segment (`ulimit -d`)
> - "fsize": maximum size of new files (`ulimit -f`)
> - "locks": maximum number of file locks (`ulimit -x`)
> - "memlock": maximum amount of locked memory (`ulimit -l`)
> - "msgqueue": maximum amount of data in message queues (`ulimit -q`)
> - "nice": niceness adjustment (nice -n, ulimit -e)
> - **"nofile": maximum number of open files (`ulimit -n`)**
> - "nofile": maximum number of open files (1048576);
> - when run by root "nproc": maximum number of processes (`ulimit -u`)
> - "nproc": maximum number of processes (1048576);
> - when run by root "rss": maximum size of a process's (`ulimit -m`)
> - "rtprio": maximum real-time scheduling priority (`ulimit -r`)
> - "rttime": maximum amount of real-time execution between blocking syscalls
> - "sigpending": maximum number of pending signals (`ulimit -i`) "stack": maximum stack size (`ulimit -s`)

What are soft-limits and hard-limits, those are documented in `man limits.conf`,

> - `hard` for enforcing hard resource limits. These limits are set by the superuser and enforced by the Kernel. The user cannot raise his requirement of system resources above such values.
> - `soft` for enforcing soft resource limits. These limits are ones that the user can move up or down within the permitted range by any pre-existing hard limits. The values specified with this token can be thought of as default values, for normal system usage.

;tldr: sets the hard and soft limits imposed by the kernel on the amount of open files you can have.